# When using UIImage(image: CGImage) PNG quality is bad

Tags: ios, uiimage, cgimage

When I:

```
return UIImage.FromBundle("myresource");
```

quality is perfect, but when I do:

```
UIImage markerImage = UIImage.FromBundle("myresource");
return new UIImage(markerImage.CGImage);
```

image is "blurred". Can anyone explain me why it happens like that?

Comment: what is your rendering mode for image. Make it as aspectFit.

Comment: The actual image size must be (too) small as compared to the UIImageView size.

Comment: How are you looking at your image to see that it's "blurred"? Doing a quick test, checking the resulting images in Debug, and the result for me is identical images.